# How to connect and configure SFTP in destination server

Tags: sftp, winscp

I want to do SFTP. I have created a public key from my source server.  I don't know how to load/configure into my destination server.

These are the steps, I have done in my server

- I have installed putty in my destination server.
- I have created a username and password in local destination machine.
- Default folder structure has been created.
- I have copied in the default file path.

I want to know step by step procedure to configure. Am i right? I cannot find `.ssh` folder in the destination folder.

Guide me the procedure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the remote server will be the SFTP server, and the local will be the client?

Comment: yes you are correct